# Logged in user session details from Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to find out a logged in user session when authenticating the user from Azure AD (with OAuth2 authorize code grant flow). The reason i need to find out user session is because, my application shouldn't allow another session for the same user from another device/browser if the user is currently logged in.
I have registered my app in AD using App registrations with application ID, client secret for the auth flow. I also checked user sign in activities log for this info but this really tells me if user had a successful or failed login into the application.

Can you please guide me if there is a way to know the active sessions for a logged in user in Azure AD (I am using non B2C tenant)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure AD session information is stored locally in the client devices** and as such can be kept alive for the initially expected time or removed at will. Due this the aforementioned, Azure AD cannot keep track of a user active sessions. However, you're welcomed to implement you own active user sessions tracking system.